# Can't use pdfbook2

Tags: pdfcrop, pdfbook

Following situation: I would like to use pdfbook2 to convert a PDF file.
I entered the following command in Windows Powershell:

> python3 C:\tmp\pdfbook2 C:\tmp\book.pdf

[image]

But every time this error message appears. Can anyone give me a good explanation so that I can easily convert PDFs via pdfbook2?
(I am relatively new to LaTex)

Comment: This doesn't look like a LaTeX tool?

Comment: go into the tmp folder and try without absolute pathes.

Comment: @JosephWright pdfcrop is mentioned in the error.